# C++ Quick Sort using Boolean true / false

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, boolean

```
int partition(int array[], int lowindex, int highindex, bool reversed) {

    int midpoint = lowindex + (highindex - lowindex) / 2;
    int pivot = array[midpoint];
    
    int low = lowindex;
    int high = highindex;

    if(reversed != true){
        bool done = false;
        while (!done) {
            while (array[low] < pivot) {
                low = low + 1;
            }

            while (pivot < array[high]) {
                high = high - 1;
            }

            if (low >= high) {
                done = true;
            }
            else {
                int temp = array[low];
                array[low] = array[high];
                array[high] = temp;
                low = low + 1;
                high = high - 1;
            }
        }
        return high;
    }

    else{
        bool done = false;
        while (!done) {

            while (array[low] > pivot) {
                low = low + 1;
            }
            while (pivot > array[high]) {
                high = high - 1;
            }

            if (low >= high) {
                done = true;
            }
            else {
                int temp = array[low];
                array[low] = array[high];
                array[high] = temp;
                low = low + 1;
                high = high - 1;
            }
        }
        return high;
    }
}



void quickSort(int array[], int lowindex, int highindex, bool reversed) {


    if (highindex <= lowindex) {
        return;
    }

    int high = partition(array, lowindex, highindex, reversed);

    quickSort(array, lowindex, high);

    quickSort(array, high + 1, highindex);


}



int main() {
    
    cout << "Quick sort an array: " << endl;
    int array2[] = {6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4};
    quickSort(array2, 0, size-1);
    printArray(array2, 0, size-1);

    int array3[] = {6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4};
    cout << "Quick sort an array in descending order:" << endl;
    quickSort(array3, 0, size-1, true);
    printArray(array3, 0, size-1);

}
```

There are two cases that are tested, one where there is no Boolean input which is expected to return the array sorted in ascending order, and one where the Boolean input is "true" and the array is expected to be sorted in descending order.

I have my program to the point where once ran this is the output I receive:

```
Quick sort an array: 
[-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Quick sort an array in descending order:
[5, 6, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The array is correctly sorted in ascending order however the descending order isn't working. I know that changing the ">" and "<" signs in the while loops are what change the sort order, however it seems as if the boolean statement isn't being recognized because the changes only affect the first if statement. I assume that the problem lies in my utilization of the "bool reversed" but I can't see where I went wrong. Any pointers or help would be appreciated!

Comment: You forgot to pass `reversed` to the recursive calls to `quickSort`. Looking at the value of `reversed` in a debugger would have shown you the issue.

Comment: IMHO, you should use the words *ascending* and *descending* instead of *reverse*.  If I reorder the array so that the order is "reversed", I haven't sorted it.  However, if I sort the array in *descending* order, I can be assured that the maximum element is first and the least valued element is last.

Comment: You may want to pass a *function object* or *functor* to your sorting, instead of the `reverse` parameter.  Your sort function can call the functor to compare or *order* the two items.  This allows you to set up ascending or descending without changing your sort function; just slip in the ordering functor.